# How to find and delete a shortcut in any directory based on the shortcut destination?

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

How does one create a batch file to search all directories for, and delete, shortcuts which point to a specific destination (such as `C:\App\Program.exe`) without regard to the file name?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to start by doing a scan for *.lnk files and use powershell functions for cleanly introspecting each shortcut.
Like this function that looks into the public Desktop folder, found at MS technet;
It's not a ready made solution, but I guess you'll have fun making it so..

```
function Get-DesktopShortcuts{
    $Shortcuts = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "C:\users\public\Desktop" -Include *.lnk
    $Shell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
    foreach ($Shortcut in $Shortcuts)
    {
        $Properties = @{
        ShortcutName = $Shortcut.Name;
        ShortcutFull = $Shortcut.FullName;
        ShortcutPath = $shortcut.DirectoryName
        Target = $Shell.CreateShortcut($Shortcut).targetpath
        }
        New-Object PSObject -Property $Properties
    }

[Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Shell) | Out-Null
}

$Output = Get-DesktopShortcuts
$Output | Out-GridView
```